# Visual Studio Marketplace not connecting in Extensions Panel

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017, 2019 and 2022, the "manage extensions" dialog box fails to connect to the vs marketplace.  It just says "Retrieving information" and never returns any result. This happens when I try to browse "online" extensions and when I try to see if there are any "updates".

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check your firewall and antivirus settings. I had a very similar problem in the past, when I blocked Windows from sending the telemetry. Visual Studio and its extensions had issues with the update. I had to remove the corresponding rules in the Windows firewall.

As a test, I just added a blocking outbound rule to the Windows firewall for `marketplace.visualstudio.com` with IP `13.107.42.18`. VS reported an error immediately, when I tried to update the extensions. However, the message was a bit different from yours:

[image]

UPDATE:
After several more attempts, I got exactly the same error as you:
[image]

You can disable the firewall temporarily and check if it works. If it works, you should check your firewall rules and [add allowing rules for VS services](https://windowsreport.com/firewall-blocking-visual-studio/). Here's [the full list of MS servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vs-2022) that may be interesting for you.

If the firewall was not the cause, you can check the proxy server and antivirus settings.

Comment: I tried disabling AV and Firewall. Didn't help.

Comment: Does `ping 13.107.42.18` work for you? Of course, there may be different IPs involved, but this one was used on my side when I checked for the updates.

Comment: Ping works fine.

Comment: Now it's working. So weird, no idea what caused or fixed this